# Visual Studio's Object Explorer shows no summaries

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, nuget

I have just downloaded several NuGet packages like `Google.Apis`, `Google.GData.Client`, ... using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

Unfortunately I can't see any details (e.g. summary) from within the object explorer, like I do when looking up e.g. `System.Console.WriteLine()`

[image]

Here the summary and exception sections are missing.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to set some option from within Visual Studio to download extra documentation from the NuGet repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary for Google.GData.Client also does not exist after I install the package.

But I found that other references exists summaries except Google.GData.Client, for example, Google.Apis,Google.Apis.Core,Google.Apis.PlatformServices, etc. Therefore, **Whether the summary exists or not is related to the package itself**. More specifically, It`s related to the author of the package. If the author of the package does not write the summary, we will not see it on the object explorer.

In order to verify this view, I have created a package, not care about the summary, then installed this package. The summary for test package does not exist as expect.

[image]

Hope those could help you.